# Como funciona a instalação de pacotes do mesmo vendor no composer?

Tags: composer

Estou com uma dúvida, vamos supor que tenho duas bibliotecas (pacotes diferentes) que podem ser instalados via composer, o **name** no arquivo composer.json é respectivamente:

- Empresa/financeiro
- Empresa/equipes

A primeira tem o autoload:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "financeiro\\": "empresa/financeiro/"
        }
}
```

O outro autoload tem:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "equipe\\": "empresa/equipe/"
        }
}
```

Se eu aplicar um composer install **empresa/financeiro** e posteriormente fizer o mesmo com **equipe**, ambos ficarão abaixo de /vendor/empresa? E o autoload, serão mesclados em um único arquivo json?

Comment: Ambos ficam no mesmo diretório, já o autoload, o composer monta seguindo o composer.json do repositório, ele não mescla, mas sabe que empresa/equipe está em um diretório e empresa/financeiro em outro.

Comment: Então dentro do autoload->por-4 teríamos duas linhas correto, uma para empresa/equipe e outro para empresa/financeiro?

Comment: Eu creio que seja bem mais complexo que isso, Fabio. O mais importante é que, como o @lvcs mencionou, o Composer toma conta disso, separa os namespaces corretamente e mesmo que estejam dentro do mesmo diretório, você não precisará se preocupar.